# how to respond parameter name instead of its Id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nosql

I am beginner with backend ,
I've learning `nodeJs` and `Mongoose`

I respond **blog posts** like this

```
[
{ 
title:"post title" ,
category : 1,
content : "lorem epsom ... "
},
...
]
```

and this is my **controller** code

```
exports.get = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const posts= await Post.find()
        res.send(posts)
    } catch (err) { next(err) }
}
```

But now I want to respond like this :

```
[
{ 
title:"post title" ,
category : "category A",
content : "lorem epsom ... "
},
...
]
```

categories are saved into another table named **Category**
so how can I send category name instead of its Id ?

Comment: You will have to use $lookup https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: @CharchitKapoor How about populate method ?

Comment: That can be tried as well. Try this `await Post.find().populate('category').exec((err, output) => {})`